# Automatic vertical scroll of element

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to use jQuery to make an element automatically scroll. Here's my code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery( '.device_screenshot' ).each(function(){

        y = jQuery(this);

        var times;
        var moveInter;
        var backInter;
        function moveBack(){
            clearInterval(moveInter);
            backInter = setInterval(function(){
                times -= 5;
                y.scrollTop(times);
                if(times == 0){
                    return startMove();
                }
            }, 1);
        }
        function move(){
            moveInter = setInterval(function(){
                times++;
                y.scrollTop(times);
                if(times == 1200){
                    return moveBack();
                }
            }, 5);
        }
        function startMove(){
            times = 0;
            if(backInter != null){
                clearInterval(backInter);
            }
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                move();
            }, 2000);
        }
        startMove();        

    });

});
```

This code makes the last element carrying the "device_screenshot" class scroll, but none of those before that. Why?

Just in case here's the HTML. It's WordPress so there are some WP-related plugin PHP functions in it:

```
<h2><?php the_field( $tablo[$i][0] ); ?></h2>
<?php   
if ( get_field( $tablo[$i][2] ) ) {
    ?>  
        <div class='desktop_wrap'>
            <div class='desktop'>               
                <div class='desktop_caption'>
                    <div class='caption_inner'>
                        <?php if ( get_field( $tablo[$i][1] ) ) { ?>
                            <div class='screenshot_text'>
                                <h3>DESKTOP (960px)</h3>
                                <?php the_field( $tablo[$i][1] ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='desktop_screenshot device_screenshot'><img class='img_p' alt='' src="<?php the_field( $tablo[$i][2] ); ?>" /></div>                 
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}   
if ( get_field( $tablo[$i][4] ) ) {
    ?>
        <div class='phone_wrap'>
            <div class='phone'>                 
                <div class='phone_caption'>
                    <div class='caption_inner'>
                        <?php if ( get_field( $tablo[$i][3] ) ) { ?>
                            <div class='screenshot_text'>
                                <h3>PHONE (320px)</h3>
                                <?php the_field( $tablo[$i][3] ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='phone_screenshot' class='phone_screenshot device_screenshot'><img class='img_p' alt='' src="<?php the_field( $tablo[$i][4] ); ?>" /></div>                 
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
if ( get_field( $tablo[$i][6] ) ) {
    ?>
        <div class='tablet_wrap'>
            <div class='tablet'>                        
                <div class='tablet_caption'>
                    <div class='caption_inner'>
                        <?php if ( get_field( $tablo[$i][5] ) ) { ?>
                            <div class='screenshot_text'>
                                <h3>IPAD (768px)</h3>
                                <?php the_field( $tablo[$i][5] ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php }?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='tablet_screenshot device_screenshot'><img class='img_p' alt='' src="<?php the_field( $tablo[$i][6] ); ?>" /></div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I just added the HTML.

Comment: No one knows why because you did not mention when you actually run the jquery code

Comment: I edited the JS. I run it in ready() function.

Comment: @drake035 take a look at the answer by noata, currently in your code, there is nothing that would actually scroll any element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the main problem but I guess you might want to change these lines:

```
y.scrollTop = times;
```

to

```
y.scrollTop(times);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/t6xj8/16/

The document of `.scrollTop()` is here :
http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

---

**EDIT:**
Your code might go like this:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/t6xj8/16/

```
function Scroller(y){

    this.times = 0;
    this.moveInter = 0;
    this.backInter = 0;

    this.moveBack = function () {
        var self = this;
        clearInterval(this.moveInter);
        this.backInter = setInterval(function () {
            self.times -= 5;
            y.scrollTop(self.times);
            if (self.times == 0) {
                return self.startMove();
            }
        }, 1);
    }

    this.move = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.moveInter = setInterval(function () {
            self.times++;
            y.scrollTop(self.times);
            if (self.times == 1200) {
                return self.moveBack();
            }
        }, 5);
    }

    this.startMove = function() {
        this.times = 0;
        var self = this;
        if (this.backInter != null) {
            clearInterval(this.backInter);
        }
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            self.move();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
jQuery('.device_screenshot').each(function () {

    y = jQuery(this);
    var scroller = new Scroller(y);
    scroller.startMove();

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks naota, it works better now. But it works only for the last DOM element carrying the "device_screenshot" class: http://jsfiddle.net/t6xj8/6/. Would you know why?

Comment: @drake035, thanks. This is because the callback functions are not bind to the each DOM element. To achieve this, you can make a class object for each elements. I update my answer, so please check .